# Height of browser header and OS header

Tags: css, breakpoints

I would like to implement a breakpoint that takes into account the viewport height as in the example below:

```
 @media (min-width: 2560px) and  (min-height: 1440px){
   zoom:1.25;
 }
```

But how do I take into account the browser header and the OS's header, eg. on mac there is a top toolbar. Do these have standard heights which I can just subtract from the min-height declared in my breakpoint?

Comment: Why do you need to know the toolbar height?  The `height` and `width` in a media query are about the viewport (the visible area that is avalible for rendering the webpage).

Comment: Because for example I want it to meet that condition on screens that size but it won't because of the browser header and OS header @t.niese

Comment: `@media (min-width: 2560px) and  (min-height: 1440px)`  will match if the area to view the webpage it has a width of at least `2560px`  and  height of at least `1440px`. This is not about the width and height of the window or the screen. So I don't get why any part of the surrounding window is relevant for you there?

Comment: On mobile devices, there might be problems if you have to take the notch, punch-hole camera, or rounded corners into account. Because those are inside of the viewport. And for that you can use [`env()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env()) to query the save area of the viewport. But the toolbars on desktop browsers are outside of the viewport.

Comment: @t.niese I'm trying to target a the specific screen size of 2560 × 1440px, so if viewed on that a screen of that size it won't pass through that breakpoint defined because the height will be a bit less.

Comment: But `@media (min-width: 2560px) and  (min-height: 1440px)` doesn't target the screen or windows size. Those values target the size of the viewport (how much of the webpage can currently be visible in the window). On which OS/Browser does this size not match the inner part of the window in your case?

Comment: @t.niese Exactly, so that's the problem, I want the breakpoint min-height to include the header. It won't match on any browser and on MacOs for example. The height will be around 1340px for example.

Comment: Ok, but could you explain what problem you want to solve here? Normally you don't care about the screen/window size, but only on how much of the webpage can be shown. Why do you care about a size that cannot be used for displaying content instead of just caring about the size that can be used?

Comment: @t.niese because I'm targeting that specific screen size.

Comment: Targeting the screen size is a bad idea. What if the screen size is  2560x1440 but the window is not in fullscreen mode, but only takes half of the screen because the user has it in split-screen mode. That's why `device-width`, `device-height`, … are deprecated and will be removed. You don't gain any useful information from the screen size when displaying information. And due to that only the viewport size is the recommended and in the future only available way for media queries.

Answer (score 0):

The `width` and `height` of a media query are defined to match the viewport (the part in the window that displays the webpage). And the viewport is the only reliable information that can be used to determine how much space you have to display your information.

There are also [`device-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width), [`device-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-height), `min-device-width` and `min-device-height`, but those have been deprecated because they won't provide any useful information on how much space is available to display information. Knowing how large the screen is, does not tell you anything about how the viewport currently looks like, and also not what the maximum extend of it could be. The window could be in split-screen mode, there could be a sidebar in the browser the occupies space, … .

There are things that can be inside of the viewport like the notch or punch-hole cameras on mobile devices, or round corners the might be problematic for headers and footers. Those can be queried using [`env()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env()).

But you can't query for the window size or the toolbar size using media queries. There is nothing in the CSS specification that provides that information.

[image: Illustartion of differnt sizes]